# how to logout without logout.php

Tags: php, logout, login-script

The php code below is login_successful.php which is obtained after user logs in, in this page i want to display his 'username' and a logout link

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:home.html");
}

?>
</head>
<body>
Welcome $myusername //here i want to display logged in user's name
Login Successful

</body>
</html>
```

how should i put logout link in this page without using another logout.php file.

Comment: `session_is_registered`: "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."

Comment: hmm, so you want to have a logout feature, but without logout.php file? any reason why you want so?

Comment: @DanLee oh, could you please suggest me an alternative code to get the work done?

Comment: @Serg I don't want ppl to know my directory structure.

Comment: @Rao that's not a reason, put it wherever you like and call it like you want to. it could be in a root folder, in other subfolder. It doesnt need to have anything actually, simply killing session value or cookie.

Answer (score 4):

Why use another page for logout? Do it like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
  //Unset cookies and other things you want to
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: login.php'); //Dont forget to redirect
  exit;
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="logout" />
</form>
```

Comment: In the past I've had a number of problems with session destroy on its own, ive always found its best to use: session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(), '', 0, '/');
session_regenerate_id(true);

Comment: @Adam that's why I commented that he can do whatever he wants to unset and destroy ;)

Comment: @Adam session_unset() is for php4 mostly. It simply doesn't work with the $_SESSION variables

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks!! but how to do this with a 'link' and not a form button?

Comment: You can add a GET variable in your link: `<a href="website.com/current_page.php?logout=1">Logout</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check wheter session has his username and then display, something like:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo "Hello, " . $_SESSION['username']);
   echo "<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always call [session_destroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to (guess what) destroy your sessions! From the manual:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.

More important than use `session_destroy()` is to make sure you reseted the cookie (if any used) by setting it's time one hour back: `time() - 3600`, like:

```
setcookie ("YourCookieName", "", time() - 3600);
```